# How to pass value from looped table index and show into an input box

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm stuck in trying to get the value from a looped table index. I want to show it in the `input` field. I can send a string but the looped indexes don't show in the field

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="PersonName">Person Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PersonName" name="PersonName" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="PersonName">Person Age</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PersonAge" name="PersonAge" placeholder="Age">
</div>
```

```js
            $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "/Person/getTable",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                success: function (data) {
                    debugger
                    var i = 1;
                    var j = 1;
                    $(data).each(
                               function () {
                                   $('#mytable').append('<tr><td>' + this.Id + '</td><td>' + this.name + '</td><td>' + this.age + '</td><td>' + this.country + '</td><td>' + this.city + '</td><td> <button class="delbtn" id= "' + this.Id + '"> Delete </button> <button class="editbtn" id= "' + this.Id + '"> Edit </button> </td></tr>')
                                   if (i == data.length)
                                   {
                                       $(".delbtn").click(function () {
                                           var del = $(this).attr('id');
                                           $.ajax({
                                               type: "get",
                                               url: "/Person/delRow",
                                               dataType: "json",
                                               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                               data: { del: del },
                                               success: function (data) {
                                                   alert(data)

                                               },
                                               failure: function (errMsg) {
                                                   alert("failure")
                                               }
                                           })
                                       });
                                       $(".editbtn").click(function () {
                                           var del = $(this).attr('id');
                                           $('#PersonName').val(''); // this is where i want to throw it to the input field
                                           $('#PersonAge').val();

                                       });



                                   }
                                   i = i + 1;



                               })
                }
            })
        });
```

Comment: What is `data`? `i` is not defined anywhere. You're also giving the `edit` and `delete` buttons the same `id`, so that will cause problems.

Comment: When asking a question put yourself in our shoes. Do you have enough information ? are all the elements in the provided code defined ? As the above comment mentioned you have a bunch of issues in the code and in the question. Please take a look at it and change it accordingly

Comment: i just updated the script. sorry i wasnt informative enough

Comment: what i want to do is select the edit button from the index of some entry of the table and then pass the name or age on to the input field

Comment: i hope you get what i was tryingto say. sorry im new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jquery to select corresponding value for inputs:

```js
$('#PersonName').val($(this).parent().siblings()[1].innerText);
```

In the code above:

- `$(this)` refers to the item that triggers the event meaning the button
- `.parent()` chooses the parent element of button which is a `<td>`
- `.sibling()` chooses all siblings of `<td>` element which means all the `<td>` elements in that row
- `[1]` is the second `<td>` (indexing starts from 0) which is the "name" column
- Finally `.innerText` return the text in name column

You can see the code snippet for a working example.

**Note:** Personally I would use a data tag or class for each column so if the column order is changed the code will still work correctly.
With data tag your table row generation code would look like below:

```js
$('#mytable').append('<tr><td data-Cname="Id" >' + this.Id + '</td><td data-Cname="name">' + this.name + '</td><td data-Cname="age">' + this.age + '</td><td data-Cname="country">' + this.country + '</td><td data-Cname="city">' + this.city + '</td><td> <button class="delbtn" id= "' + this.Id + '"> Delete </button> <button class="editbtn" id= "' + this.Id + '"> Edit </button> </td></tr>')
```

and selection code would look like the line below:

```js
$(this).parent().siblings("[data-Cname="name"]).text()
```

Note 2: There are better ways to avoid column order change problem but it would be out of this question scope to go through them.

```js
$(".editbtn").click(function() {
  var del = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#PersonName').val($(this).parent().siblings()[1].innerText); 
  $('#PersonAge').val($(this).parent().siblings()[2].innerText);

});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="PersonName">Person Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PersonName" name="PersonName" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="PersonName">Person Age</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PersonAge" name="PersonAge" placeholder="Age">
</div>
<table>
  <th>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Age</td>
      <td>Country</td>
      <td>City</td>
      <td> Buttons</td>
    </tr>
  </th>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>US</td>
      <td>NY</td>
      <td> <button class="delbtn" id="11"> Delete </button> <button class="editbtn" id="11"> Edit </button> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>Doe2</td>
      <td>US</td>
      <td>LA</td>
      <td> <button class="delbtn" id="12"> Delete </button> <button class="editbtn" id="12"> Edit </button> </td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You are most welcome. Please consider choosing as best answer it helped.